# Why always leak when using CLLocationManager?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, cllocationmanager

myclass.m

```
- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
}
return self;
```

}

```
- (void)dealloc {

[locationManager release];

[super dealloc];
```

}

I use instrument to check leak. The leak always point to

`self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];`

Why?

Comment: As the code is fine you should investigate (or show) other uses of that property.

Answer (score 4):

> I use instrument to check leak. The
>   leak always point to

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
```

> Why?

Because that is the line of code where *the allocation that is leaked* occurred.   Since you have balanced both implied `retain`s in that code correctly (once here, once in -dealloc -- mmccomb's suggestion of direct assignment without `autorelease` is good, but won't fix the problem), the leak is elsewhere.

Specifically, the leak will be a `retain` that isn't balanced by a `release`.  So, somewhere your are retaining the object and not releasing it.

Instruments can be used to show all retain/release events on any given object.  Use that and look through the list of events related to your leaked object.  There will be one more retain than release.   Pair off the retains and releases.  Whichever retain is left without a balanced release is the cause.

I wrote an article about using [Heapshot analysis in Instruments](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) to detect memory abuse.   It includes discussion and screenshots showing the retain/release event inspector and will be applicable.

Comment: I follow the guide of "Heapshot analysis in Instruments". I do find a retain message like this: "# Category Event Type RefCt Timestamp Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Caller
16 CFRunLoopTimer CFRetain 5 01:20.195.643 0x185230 0 CoreLocation -[CLLocationManagerInternal dealloc]", and it point to "[locationManager release];

    [super dealloc];" in dealloc in myclass.m. Is it the problem?

Comment: @bbum  I mean locationManager should be release in dealloc, but it retains, what's wrong with it ?  Would you like to give me you email, I will send you the screen shots.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the retain/release inventory for the object in question?  *That* particular retain sounds like an internal implementation detail of the framework (note that it is CLLocationManagerInternal).

Comment: @bbum Thanks! But how to post screenshot here?

Comment: Hit shift-cmd-4 to take a screenshot of portion of screen. Edit your question. Click the little picture icon to attach screenshot.

Comment: @bbum i am not allowed to post image. Would you like to give me you email? Send to my email yzx2002@gmail.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using the self. setter notation in init methods.  When an object is being initialised there is no guarantee that it is in a consistent state.  Change your implementation to directly set the ivar as follows...

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

You no longer need the autorelease call which was previously accounting for the extra retain count brought about by invoking the setter.  You do however need to release the object in your dealloc method (as you are already doing).

Comment: i use these codes instead:`- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
        locationManager.delegate = self; 
    }
    return self;
}` But is also leak.

Answer (score -3):

You can explicitly check the retain count in dealloc like so:

```
NSLog(@"locationManager retain count: %d", [locationManager retainCount]);
```

If it is more than 1, check where else you may be retaining it - like if you assign it to another retaining property (e.g. declared with retain keyword). You can add that NSLog call in other locations before and after you do something with locationManager and see where the retain count increases. Sometimes it may not be immediately obvious.

Another possibility: does the dealloc method even get called? Perhaps the whole "myclass" object is not properly released? (Although I suppose in that case you'd see a leak of type "myclass", too).

Comment: why not? It's not like I suggest relying on it in production, but I think it is quite useful for finding where an unexpected/overlooked retain happens.

Comment: @SVD because it can be *easily* misinterpreted. You should use Instruments instead, which will give far more detailed information.  `-retainCount` shouldn't even exist. It should be deprecated and should produce static analysis warnings if you ever try to invoke it.

Comment: I remember that there is another leak in the class that use myclass.Codes like this` [self.navigationController pushViewController:myclass animated:YES];`

Comment: @Dave DeLong Well, in this case Instruments aren't very helpful, are they? And if before [something somecall:locationManager] retainCount is N, and it becomes N+1 after somecall, then you might want to look in somecall: to see if locationManager gets retained and not released somewhere within. Not the silver bullet, but it did help me a couple of times, that's why I thought it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: @tobytaro OK, so is dealloc being called in myclass? And the object (lets call it object A) that does pushViewController:myclass, does it ever pop it? And does object A get dealloced itself?

Comment: @SVD How can I confirm dealloc is being called in myclass?  I use NavigationController Class to be the rootview of my app, so it automatically has a "back" button on the navigation bar of myclass's view.

Comment: **Do not ever use retainCount**.  Instruments is perfectly helpful, if you use it correctly.  It is extremely effective in tracking down memory abuse of all kinds, not just leaks.

Comment: @tobytaro add NSLog(@"myclass dealloc") to dealloc and look for it in the logs.